# Flask-SqlAlchemy relationship error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is simple model I have

```
  class Record(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'reg_records'
      request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
      title = db.Column(NVARCHAR())

  class Field(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'reg_fields'
      request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True) 
      name = db.Column(NVARCHAR(), primary_key = True)
```

Now I want to map releated fields to record. I'm following flask-sqlalchemy specs and getting this

```
  class Field(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'reg_fields'
      request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('record.request_id'), primary_key= True) 
      name = db.Column(NVARCHAR(), primary_key = True)

  class Record(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'reg_records'
      request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
      title = db.Column(NVARCHAR())
      fields = db.relationship(Field, backref = 'record')
```

However when I try to use this model I'm getting following error

```
  sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError
  NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Record.fields - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Adding `primaryjoin` to the relationship declaration like below

```
    fields = db.relationship(Field, backref = 'record', primaryjoin='Record.request_id==Field.request_id')
```

Doesnt solve the problem, but instead gives new exception

```
    sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError
    NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'reg_fields.request_id' could not find table 'record' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'request_id'
```

If I replace class names with table names in primaryjoin value,

```
    fields = db.relationship(Field, backref = 'record', primaryjoin='reg_records.request_id==reg_fields.request_id')
```

I'm getting one another exception

```
   sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
   InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: 'Table' object has no attribute 'request_id'
```

Overall, what is right way setting up one-to-many relationship in flask-sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do. I am assuming that you are trying to make a one-to-many relationship between Record and Field (one Record can have zero or many Fields). I am also assuming that you want to have only one Field named *name* per record. The following models set up the tables and relationships as I believe that you want them:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint

class Record(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reg_records'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(NVARCHAR())


class Field(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reg_fields'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('record_id', 'name', name='record_id_name_uix'),
    )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    record_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey(Record.id))
    name = db.Column(NVARCHAR())

    record = db.relationship(Record, backref='fields')
```

You can now do things like creating new Records and Fields:

```
record = Record(title='a record')
record.fields.append(Field(name='field1'))
record.fields.append(Field(name='field2'))
db.session.add(record)
db.session.commit()
```

However, try to create two Fields with the same name for the same Record, you will get an IntegrityError when you try to commit them:

```
record = Record(title='another record')
record.fields.append(Field(name='same_name'))
record.fields.append(Field(name='same_name'))
db.session.add(record)
db.session.commit()
```

Lastly, please try to be more careful with how your Python code is formatted, it is very hard to read as it stands.

Comment: You are right, I want to have one-to-many relationship between Record and Field, so Record has multiple Fields and name is unique within one record. I'm mapping it to view so there is no real primary key, that is why both reqest_id and name were set to primary_key.

Comment: Anyway, moving relatioship to the Field class did the trick , however all examples were showing it the way I did it initially.